# What is '#' in php?

Tags: php

In my php page code there is a line as follows:

```
##|*IDENT=page-system-advanced-admin
```

Is this a comment line? If not what is it? I searched online but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: The syntax highlighting has answered your question for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> PHP supports 'C', 'C++' and Unix shell-style (Perl style) comments. For example:

```
<?php
    echo 'This is a test'; // This is a one-line c++ style comment
    /* This is a multi line comment
       yet another line of comment */
    echo 'This is yet another test';
    echo 'One Final Test'; # This is a one-line shell-style comment
?>
```

[PHP Comments documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php)

Comment: i had a felling that its a comment, but wasn't sure. Thanks.